# Window.Print() adds scroll to page and does not print the entire content

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, scroll

I can't figure why window.print() is adding scroll to this page. The page is really big and has the scroll bar, but shouldn't the content break in different pages? Even removing the overflow from all classes it won't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try showing overflow on print with css:

```
@media print
{    
    html {
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
}
```

you can change any css class of any element for print using "@media print" and "!important". Try "display: none;" for your scrollbar (if it's a custom scrollbar) too.